# How can I express this query using Hibernate's HQL and Criteria api?

Tags: hibernate

SELECT CITIES.* FROM CITIES WHERE CITIES.STATE_ID IN (SELECT STATES.STATE_ID from STATES WHERE STATES.COUNTRY_ID = 78)

### EDIT:

Here are the classes

### Country.java

```
Integer id;
String name;
```

### State.java

```
Integer id;
Integer countryId;
String name;
```

### City.java

```
Integer id;
Integer stateId;
String name;
```

I'm trying to get all the cities that belong to certain country (say, the one having its id = 78)

Answer (score 3):

Criteria api works with relational mapping. If there isn't any relation between City, State or Country you can not use something like the above solution. I have two suggestions, Firstly you can use two criterias.

```
DetachedCriteria ownerCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(State.class);
ownerCriteria.setProjection(Property.forName("id"));
ownerCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("countryId", countryParam));


Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(City.class);
criteria.add(Property.forName("stateId").in(ownerCriteria));
```

Second one is using hql with cross join. Have a look at [here](http://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/hibernate_hql_inner_join_on_clause).

Finally i think is better to write this query with native sql. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say when you do not display your mapping and/or domain classes.
Still, you do not need a subquery for this query (although it will return the same results, and is perfectly ok).

You can do it like this:

```
ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria <City>();
crit.CreateAlias ("State", "s");
crit.CreateAlias ("s.Country", "cntry");
crit.Add (Expression.Eq ("cntry.Id", 78));

var results = crit.List<City>();
```